# How to set two message handlers in one function

Tags: python, python-3.x, messenger, bale-messenger

I want to set both TemplateResponseFilter and TextFilter in one message handler in a function. i used one handler before like this:

```
@dispatcher.message_handler(TextFilter(pattern=["start"]))
```

but i couldn't set both of them. any one can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this sample code

```
@dispatcher.message_handler(
filters=[TemplateResponseFilter(pattern=TMessage.start), TextFilter(keywords="start")])
```